# text in the textbox doesnt retain its format

Tags: asp.net, formatting, textbox

I have asp.net application, in which there is a textbox to enter some text. The application will send mail to users. The date whatever they enter in the texbox is the body of the mail. The issue the formatting is not retained in the outcome of the mail. It's cumbersome.

For example I enter following text in textbox :

> SAMPLE : Testing the issue.
>
> EXAMPLE : Checking for the same .

the outcome of mail look like following :

> sample : testing the issue.example : checking for the same.

I want the outcome to be same as the data we enter in the texbox with formatting.

Comment: In which language r u writting ur code part VB or C#

Comment: I don't know anything about asp.net, but you need to use a function that converts newline characters `\n` to HTML newlines `<br>`

Comment: Is the mail HTML formatted?  If so, your carriage returns probably need to be converted to line break tags.

Comment: A function to convert newlines to HTML breaks is in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the replace function on the string:

```
string mystring = textbox.Text;
mystring = mystring.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

Make sure that your email body is set to HTML, and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In code behind you can use `Constants.vbCrLf` in C#.net or `vbCrLf` in VB.net for making it to take the next line, which will appear as ur input.

Comment: HOW TO USE IT DO I HAVE TO REPLACE THE TEXTBOX.TEXT WITH vBCRLF

Comment: No, u are appending the text which is entering in the text box to be displaying it in the mail right, there after the first text box's text u have to concat this one according to ur language.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this attribute? `.IsBodyHtml = True`

write html tags directly on your textarea, this should work. Example: < p>SAMPLE : Testing the issue.< /p> < p>EXAMPLE : Checking for the same .< /p>

Comment: I HAVE SET .ISBODYHTML = TRUE, USING c#

Comment: Now write html tags directly on your textarea, this should work. Example: <p>SAMPLE : Testing the issue.</p>

<p>EXAMPLE : Checking for the same .</p>