# Display txt file contents in asp.net textbox or other

Tags: c#, asp.net

i was tring to write txt file data to a textbox, but it shows my data as one word without spaces. How do I write txt file content to a textbox and save its formatting? There is the code i tried:

```
 private void WriteData()
{
    if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("App_Data/U3.txt")))
    {
        TextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("App_Data/U3.txt"));
    }
    File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("App_Data/U3.txt"), TextBox1.Text);
}
```

Edit: apparently it doesnt remove spaces, but new lines are gone and its all in one line
Edit 2: alright now im trying to use ReadAllLines but how do i make this statement valid

```
TextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("App_Data/U3.txt"));
```

Comment: That shouldnt remove spaces!

Comment: @BugFinder you are right it doesnt, but it does delete new lines and write everything in one, should I use ReadAllLines instead?

Comment: Why you are putting it in `textBox`, why don't you try to put it in `textArea` and test your code.

Comment: @zerociudo then its not showing it as 1 word is it... its showing it as 1 line...

Comment: is "TextBox1" set to multi-line mode or not?

Comment: @ADyson yeah it wasnt.. my bad... Thanks for answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First go to properties and change Textmode to Multi line and then try below code. It works.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string file = "test.txt";
        string[] str = null;
        if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(file)))
        {
            str = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath(file));
        }
        foreach (string s in str)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text +"\n"  +s;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to replace all newlines in the file output to `<br/>` tags, like this:

```
mystring.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

ps. I found that answer here:
[text in the textbox doesnt retain its format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124524/text-in-the-textbox-doesnt-retain-its-format)